# Scraping a dynamically loading website with php curl

Tags: php, php-curl

I am new to scraping and have scrapped two websites formally. But the problem appeared to me when I tried to scrape dynamic loading websites. When the website is rendered with JavaScript, I am unable to scrape the contents of the website then.

Is there any way I can scrape the contents of that website using `php curl` or any other client related to `PHP`?

This is what I have done so far :

```js
$link = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=0&suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword=android+developer&sc.keyword=android+developer&locT=N&locId=192&jobType=";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
$data = curl_exec($ch);


$document = new DOMdocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document->loadHTML($data);
$elements = $document->getElementsByTagName("div");

foreach($elements as $element){
   echo $element->nodeValue."<br>";;
}
```

Comment: Do some research please ... https://www.google.com/search?q=scrape+website+populated+by+javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need headless browser for this, you can use PHP Wrapper for **PhantomJS** , here is the link http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/. This will solve your problem. It has following features:

- Load webpages through the PhantomJS headless browser
- View detailed response data including page content, headers, status code etc.
- Handle redirects
- View javascript console errors

Hope this helps.