# Wait for the JS to be executed before scraping the page

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to scrape the following page using [hQuery](https://github.com/duzun/hQuery.php): http://www.oddsportal.com/search/Paris+SG/soccer/

I realised half way that the odds of each game are included using JS (before, it's just `-`). Is there any way to get the page after the javascript has been executed or should I find another website??

Comment: hQuery is not a browser, it will only download the HTML page and will not execute any javascript code. You'll need to find a different way to get any information that is generated/loaded by javascript.

Comment: @rickdenhaan is there maybe a way to retrieve the html after the JS has been executed using any other tool in PHP? Then I would be able to process it though hQuery. Otherwise I guess I will find an other website.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, although that doesn't say much ;-) But looking at that site, the current odds appear to come from an active websocket that's streaming updated values every couple of seconds. If you can connect to that socket from your server using PHP, you might be able to retrieve the data.

Comment: However, depending on what you want to do with the data once you have it, you might be violating their [Terms of Use](http://www.oddsportal.com/terms/) (under Intellectual Property): "Without prior authorisation in writing from the Provider, Visitors are not authorised to copy, modify, tamper with, distribute, transmit, display, reproduce, transfer, upload, download or otherwise use or alter any of the content of the Website. "

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you would have to use another browser (not hQuery) and look into the code and see if there are any events that are emitted that you can catch up on.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot using PHP

Scraping a site gives you whatever the server responds with to the HTTP request that you make (from which the "initial" state of the DOM tree is derived, if that content is HTML). It cannot take into account the "current" state of the DOM after it has been modified by Javascript.

You can using other powerful tools like selenium

Answer (score 0):

You would need `PhantomJs` PHP wrapper for that is easy to use and gives more control and features, please see my answer here

[Scraping a dynamically loading website with php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049382/scraping-a-dynamically-loading-website-with-php-curl/49272329#49272329)

Hope it helps