# How to parse a dynamic page

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing

i have to parse a website for my stage, the problem is that the website load dynamic content after few seconds, so the parsing is getting only the first information, and the information i need is not find.

This is the website : https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=&indices%5Bprod_all_products_custom_ranking_revenuelast28d%5D%5BrefinementList%5D%5Blanguage%5D%5B0%5D=French&indices%5Bprod_all_products_custom_ranking_revenuelast28d%5D%5Bpage%5D=1&indices%5Bprod_all_products_custom_ranking_revenuelast28d%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BclickAnalytics%5D=true&indices%5Bprod_all_products_custom_ranking_revenuelast28d%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BhitsPerPage%5D=10&configure%5BclickAnalytics%5D=true&page=1

When i load the website, it loads all courses and after 2-3 secondes it applies the filter (language = french) and reload the page to display the french courses. 
The parser i use (simple html dom) parse all courses and not the page reloaded,
How can i do to parse the "final" page with filter loaded ?

I've tried basically to put a sleep(5) on my code but nothing change
This code work but it parse all the courses and not the courses with filter applied.

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');



$html = file_get_html('https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=indices%5Bprod_all_products_custom_ranking_revenuelast28d%5D%5BrefinementList%5D%5Blanguage%5D%5B0%5D=French&indices%5Bprod_all_products_custom_ranking_revenuelast28d%5D%5Bpage%5D=1&indices%5Bprod_all_products_custom_ranking_revenuelast28d%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BclickAnalytics%5D=true&indices%5Bprod_all_products_custom_ranking_revenuelast28d%5D%5Bconfigure%5D%5BhitsPerPage%5D=10&configure%5BclickAnalytics%5D=true&page=1');
sleep(10);

foreach($html->find('div.card-info') as $e)
echo $e->outertext . '<br>';


?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scraping a dynamically loading website with php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049382/scraping-a-dynamically-loading-website-with-php-curl)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install NodeJS and use [phantomjs](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs) via PHP shell_exec():

```
<?php

$result = shell_exec('phantomjs script.js')
//...
```

script.js:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();

page.open("https://www.coursera.org", function(status) {
    // Parse contents and return result
});
```

Perhaps you need a ready-made service for tracking changes, such as a [linkupdater](https://linkupdater.com) or other.